# Python if I'm capturing at 1080 by 1440 is there a way to only read the pixel value from every 10th pixel

Tags: python, image, video, resize

So the current methods for capturing a downscaled image is to capture the full thing then downscale it, but I'm trying to go fast and thus don't want to capture the full image only every 10th pixel giving me an image 144 along and 108 down. which would result in a 10X speed increase because I don't have to get all the pixels from a full resolution just the few I want.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible due to driver/library limitations, I'm thinking they'd be sending you the entire frame, try looking into the library you're using

Comment: yea I assumed so, just wondering it someone out these knew of something